# What is the difference between DINS and the regular FAA NOTAM website?

Tags: faa, notam, website

Plain and simple, what the heck is the difference between the Defense Internet NOTAM Service (DINS) and the FAA NOTAM website? They are both located behind a `faa.gov` url.

DINS Example: https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/

"Regular" NOTAMS: https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/

Thanks!

Comment: On the DINS site, it has this in red at the top of the page: `~ For DoD Flight Only ~`